# Web Part Zone not showing when edit page - Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have a Sharepoint 2010 page. It is using a page layout. 
I'm using Visual Studio 2010 for deploying the solution. When I do, it works Ok. 
When I deploy the solution using stsadm, I get an error when I try to edit a page and add a master page. When I click on "Edit", the area for adding webparts is not being shown. 
I've checked permissions and I'm logged in as an administrator. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks for your help!

PnP

Comment: What error do you get when you try to edit?

Comment: No error at all.  You just can't see the add we part area.  It's blank.  No we part zone.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to try putting IE into compatibility mode and/or using Chrome to see if the web part zones appear. IE has a pretty common bug with SharePoint that prevents the zones from appearing.